# dynamo.ioc - constructor injection example needed

Tags: .net, constructor, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, code-injection

I'm looking for a FAST IoC container and found Dynamo.IoC.

It's easy to make it work like a simple ServiceLocator, but how to use it for constructor injection?

Here are example classes

```
    private interface ITestInterface
    {

    }

    private class TestClass : ITestInterface
    {

    }

    private class TestClassWithDependency
    {
        public ITestInterface DependecyInstance { get; private set; }

        public TestClassWithDependency( ITestInterface dependencyInstance )
        {
            DependecyInstance = dependencyInstance;
        }
    }
```

And the failing test

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_Container_Resolve_WithDependency()
    {
        Container.Register<ITestInterface, TestClass>();

        var obj = Container.Resolve<TestClassWithDependency>( );


        obj.Should().NotBeNull();
        obj.DependecyInstance.Should( ).NotBeNull( );
    }
```

Comment: [Here's a good performance benchmark](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) for IoC containers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register class with the paramaterised constructor with an interface. Then register it as usual .RegisterType and you can inject the "dependencyInstance". Please see below.

```
public interface ITestInterface
{}

public class TestClass : ITestInterface
{}

public interface ITestClassWithDependency {
    ITestInterface DependecyInstance { get;  }
}

public class TestClassWithDependency : ITestClassWithDependency
{
    public ITestInterface DependecyInstance { get; private set; }


    public TestClassWithDependency(ITestInterface dependencyInstance)
    {
        DependecyInstance = dependencyInstance;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_Container_Resolve_WithDependency()
    {
        using (var container = new IocContainer())
        {
            container.Register<ITestInterface, TestClass>();
            container.Register<ITestClassWithDependency, TestClassWithDependency>();

            var obj = container.Resolve<ITestClassWithDependency>();

            Assert.IsNotNull(obj);
            Assert.IsNotNull(obj.DependecyInstance);
        }

    }
}
```